# Cannot create a for loop inside a java thread - why?

Tags: java, multithreading

my code is as follows

```
public void incomingMessageThread() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    new Thread()
    {

        BuildData a = new BuildData();
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        {
            a.parseDataFile("_"+i+"/outgoingMessages");
        }

    }.start();

}
```

I get told its an illegal start of line. If I run the code outside a thread it works fine. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Generally it's better to pass a `Runnable` into the `Thread` constructor, rather than to attempt to subclass a complicated class. It's also a good idea to follow the conventions on formatting. BTW: You'll probably need to find a different way to do the exception handling. You might not discover the file is missing until after the method had returned.

Comment: will do thanks, this was just some throw away code to process chunks of data. :)

Comment: Of course I guess I should always follow best practice even if its throw away!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using statements inside of a class and outside of a method.

From the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) for `Thread.run`: "Subclasses of Thread should override this method."

```
public void incomingMessageThread() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            BuildData a = new BuildData();
            for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
            {
                a.parseDataFile("_"+i+"/outgoingMessages");
            }
        }

    }.start();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

you should have written something like this (implement void run() )

```
public void incomingMessageThread() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
Thread t= new Thread()
    {
    public void run()
        {
        BuildData a = new BuildData();
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
          {
            a.parseDataFile("_"+i+"/outgoingMessages");
           }
        }
    };
t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread is a class not a function ( which is the closet your syntax above resembles )

your code should be

```
class MyThread : public Thread {
 public void run() {
    // code
 }
}

Thread t = new MyThread();
t.run()
```

Comment: should be t.start() not t.run()

Comment: He's trying to use an anonymous inner class.